# SignalR Rewrite Rule causes Chrome to fall back to longpolling

Tags: url-rewriting, cross-domain, signalr, server-sent-events, signalr.client

From server https://a.local, I'm connecting to a SignalR connection:

```
/gateway/signalr/status (so https://a.local/gateway/signalr/status)
```

That then hits a URL rewrite rule which handles cross domain calls.  The rule translate the request into:

```
https://b.local/signalr/status
```

This works fine and message are received.  However, in Chrome (and FF) it tries to connect with transport serverSentEvents, times out and then falls back to longPolling.

The transport serverSentEvents does connect when using a test page

```
https://b.local/signalr/test.html
```

so I know there's not a problem with this transport, just some oddness with rewrite rules.

Is there anything special I need to do to get this working?  Do I need to configure IIS in some way to get serverSentEvents working with rewrite rules?

Thanks for any help.